# How to drag text in "enhanced" textareas?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

In simple `<textarea>`s, I am able to drag a text selection, in that the selection actually moves from the original place to the new place. But on "enhanced" textareas (like GitHub comment boxes, or the StackExchange compose box I'm typing in right now) that behavior seems to be overridden and the selection isn't moved.

Interestingly, in Chrome I *am* able to drag text selections in the GitHub compose box, whereas in Firefox that doesn't work (the cursor changes to the [`alias`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor#values) form when dragging, if that helps). I am unable to drag text in the StackOverflow compose box in both Chrome and Firefox, though.

I've tried holding every combination of <kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> while dragging, but nothing seems to help. Does anyone know of a solution to this? I'd be happy to use a browser extension if that's what it takes.

Answer (score 2):

These "enhanced" textareas are created by some jQuery plugin.

They seem to allow dragging text outside to any other textarea
(but only unmanaged ones),
but dragging-in seem to have not been implemented, or forgotten.

For Stack Exchange, I suggest raising the issue on
[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/),
as it seems to be an oversight or missing implementation.